# Django Rest Framework: Updating model with ImageField without updating the image

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework I am trying to update  a model with an image field. When I try to update the other fields on the model I get this error:

```
{"image": ["No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form."]}
```

Here is a simply idea of the serializer. The image field it returns on a GET call just has the file name.

```
class ModelWithImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField('image', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Level
        fields = ('id','name', 'image')
```

How do I update my model without resubmitting the file?

Answer (score 3):

Django REST allows to submit partial `PATCH` requests ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#updatemodelmixin)). Just make sure to use an `UpdateAPIView` (or variant of this) which automatically allows this. The idea of partial updates is that they do not require you to submit all model fields which will accomplish the behavior you need.

Comment: I am using this on a 'settings' view which will have a variable amount of of fields updated. Should I focus on creating a system that builds up the PATCH data as each field changes? I'm hoping there is a way I can just tell DRF to cool it on that image field.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. When using patch you don't have to submit all fields meaning that you can just omit the image field and Django will not complain. When you will add additional fields to the model, you can do the same with them...

Comment: I could have been more clear, this is a simplified version of my model serializer. It has many other fields that can be updated via a form, so any number of them might change including the image field. With PATCH i'd have to build something to tell say which fields have been modified.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I have the same problem. Im doing a PATCH but it still complains with ["No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form."].

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a FileField.  I had to delete the FileField property on the PUT request so that it won't override the stored value.  Just make sure that blank=True on the Model so that it's an optional field.  I'm using DRF 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `ImageField` as `read_only` then it will work but when you have post method , then it won't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).